# Javascript - Change character in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using *select2* for choosing different area and different countries .I want some method in *Select2* which change specific character before I check it with data. Here is my initial code :

```
var initSearchSelect2 = function (className) {
    $(className).select2({
        language: "en",
        allowClear: true,
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'All regions',
                parent: 0,
                children: $scope.regions // here is my data
            }
        ],
        escapeMarkup: function (m) {
            return m;
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var userNeighborhood = $cookies.get("neighborhood");
            if (!isUndefinedOrNull(userNeighborhood)) {
                userNeighborhood = userNeighborhood.split(',');
                var initialVal = {
                    'city': userNeighborhood[0],
                    'text': userNeighborhood[1],
                    }
                callback(initialVal);

            }
            else {
                callback({id: 0, text: 'check it'})
            }
        },
        placeholder: "select your region ..."
    }, true);
}
```

I want to check if user search "London" , I check "England" in $scope.regions instead of "London". I used to check query and matcher in select2 like this :

```
query: function(options) {
    console.log(options);
    if(options.term) {
        options.term = options.term.replace('London','England');
    }

    return options
},
```

However I haven't reach any interesting result. Any suggestion to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override data method:

```
$ajax.select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: 'test', //put your replacement here
          page: params.page
        };
      }
    }
});
```

Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitwork/pbrr5dfg/). No matter what you enter the "test" will be always sent to the server.